# Running Sympy lambdify functions on the GPU using numba.cuda

Tags: cuda, sympy, numba

I'm trying to be able to run an arbitrary sympy lambdify function on the GPU using numba.cuda. So far I've run into errors every step of the way, due to numba.jit allowing for functions to return values, but numba.cuda.jit not permitting it (numba.cuda.jit kernels cannot return a value). This likely stems from a fundamental misunderstanding of mine on how numba works, but the examples in the documentation are somewhat sparse and I've tried mutating each of the given examples to try to do what I want to no avail.

Examples of what I've tried:

**Non-CUDA jit function (works)**

```
import sympy
from sympy.abc import y
import numba

f = sympy.lambdify(y, sympy.sin(y), 'math')
g = numba.jit(f)
g(1) #returns 0.8414709848078965
```

**CUDA jit example of the same code**

```
import sympy
from sympy.abc import y
from numba import cuda

f = sympy.lambdify(y, sympy.sin(y), 'math')
g = cuda.jit(f)
g(1) #error
```

Returns the following:

```
TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
No conversion from float64 to none for '$8return_value.3', defined at None
File "<lambdifygenerated-5>", line 2:
def _lambdifygenerated(y):
    return (sin(y))
    ^

During: typing of assignment at <lambdifygenerated-5> (2)

File "<lambdifygenerated-5>", line 2:
def _lambdifygenerated(y):
    return (sin(y))
```

This checks out because cuda functions made in this way can't return a value, but does seem to suggest that numba had no problem compiling this function for cuda, its just that it couldn't figure out what to do with the value at the end.

The (naively) obvious answer seems to be to create a function to take this value and assign it to a variable, similar to what is done in this example from the Numba documentation (https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/cuda/kernels.html#thread-positioning):

**Original code (works):**

```
import sympy
import numpy
from sympy.abc import y
from numba import cuda

f = sympy.lambdify(y, sympy.sin(y), 'math')

@cuda.jit
def increment_by_one(an_array):
    # Thread id in a 1D block
    tx = cuda.threadIdx.x
    # Block id in a 1D grid
    ty = cuda.blockIdx.x
    # Block width, i.e. number of threads per block
    bw = cuda.blockDim.x
    # Compute flattened index inside the array
    pos = tx + ty * bw
    if pos < an_array.size:  # Check array boundaries
        an_array[pos] += 1
        
array = numpy.arange(3.)
print(array) #returns [0. 1. 2.]
blockspergrid = 2
threadsperblock = 32
increment_by_one[blockspergrid, threadsperblock](array)
print(array) #returns [1. 2. 3.]
```

**Changed code (doesn't work)**

```
import sympy
import numpy
from sympy.abc import y
from numba import cuda

f = sympy.lambdify(y, sympy.sin(y), 'math')

@cuda.jit
def cuda_f(an_array):
    # Thread id in a 1D block
    tx = cuda.threadIdx.x
    # Block id in a 1D grid
    ty = cuda.blockIdx.x
    # Block width, i.e. number of threads per block
    bw = cuda.blockDim.x
    # Compute flattened index inside the array
    pos = tx + ty * bw
    if pos < an_array.size:  # Check array boundaries
        an_array[pos] = f(an_array[pos])
        
array = numpy.arange(3.)
print(array) #returns [0. 1. 2.]
cuda_f(array)
blockspergrid = 2
threadsperblock = 32
cuda_f[blockspergrid, threadsperblock](array) #error
print(array)
```

This fails with the following code:

```
TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
Untyped global name 'f': cannot determine Numba type of <class 'function'>

File "<ipython-input-7-9ef7fd8543d7>", line 19:
def cuda_f(an_array):
    <source elided>
    if pos < an_array.size:  # Check array boundaries
        an_array[pos] += f(an_array[pos])
        ^
```

This error ("cannot determine Numba type of <class 'function'>"), seems to be universally present in all my other attempts to GPU-ify this function, including attempts based on all the code snippets here: https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/cuda/ufunc.html .

Clearly this means I'm doing something wrong with how to go about this. Is this (running a sympy lambdify function in parallel on the GPU using numba.cuda) something that is possible to do?

**Edit:** I have had some small amount of success with first converting the sympy lambdify function to a numba.jit function, and then running that inside the cuda kernel. I used the following code:

```
import sympy
import numpy
from sympy.abc import y
from numba import cuda
import numba

f = sympy.lambdify(y, sympy.sin(y), 'math')
g = numba.jit(f)

@cuda.jit
def sympy_kernel(x, out):
    startx = cuda.grid(1)    
    stridex = cuda.gridsize(1) 

    for i in range(startx, x.shape[0], stridex):
        out[i] = g(x[i])

@numba.jit
def sympy_cpu(x, out):
    for i in range(len(out)):
        out[i] = g(x[i])
        
        
array = numpy.arange(100000000.)
array_device = cuda.to_device(array)
out = numpy.arange(100000000.)
out_device = cuda.to_device(out)
blockspergrid = 64
threadsperblock = 64
%timeit -n5 sympy_kernel[blockspergrid, threadsperblock](array_device, out_device); cuda.synchronize()
%timeit -n5 sympy_cpu(array, out)
out_host = out_device.copy_to_host()
print(out_host)
```

And the return values are:

```
26.9 ms ± 15.7 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 5 loops each)
958 ms ± 16.3 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 5 loops each)
[ 0.          0.84147098  0.90929743 ... -0.87103474 -0.05727351
  0.80914472]
```

Comment: sympy library is not supported in numba cuda jit kernels.  You'll need to stick to [what is listed as supported in the documentation](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/cuda/cudapysupported.html)

Comment: Gotcha, thanks for the response. Looks like I'll need to look into the other direction for explicitly converting a sympy expression into those supported python features...

Comment: the most obvious suggestion I can make is to realize your `f` function as a [cuda device function in numba](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/cuda/device-functions.html).  I acknowledge there are significant differences between that and a lambda, however.

Comment: Thank you for your help! While I thought I tried it before, I've actually just recently had some small success with first converting f into a numba.jit function, and then calling that within the cuda kernel. Not sure if this is a proper method, but it does show some reasonably significant speedup compared with the CPU version of the code. Should this not pan out for the breadth of sympy functions I'll end up needing, I'll definitely take a deeper look into those cuda device functions. Thanks again!

Comment: print the `f.__docs__` to see the code that `lamdify` produces. So far I've only looked at the `numpy` product. `lambdify` essentially does lexical substitutions according to the target language. So `synpy.sin` gets changed to `np.sin` of `math.sin`.  I don't think `numba` can reach inside that function to 'compile' it.

Answer (score 2):

> I'm trying to be able to run an arbitrary sympy lambdify function on the GPU using numba.cuda

At the current state of development, that isn't supported in Numba and cannot be done. Numba only supports a skeleton of Python language features on the GPU and if you functions can't be lowered directly to a supported `math` function, there is no external function support on the GPU.